# Fire gives the "TypeError: Expected a message object, but got field_path" error when trying to use ArrayUnion

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use firebase with python.
I have connected to the database and in the scheme as following:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db, firestore

# Initialize connection to firebase
cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
app_options = {
    'databaseURL': '...'}
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
```

Currently the database has 2 types of documents, we get the following when we convert them to dictionaries:

```py
Admin: {'users': [], 'email': '...', 'first_name': '...', 'last_name': '...'}
User: {'email': '...', 'onboarding_form': 'first_name': '...', 'last_name': '...'}
```

I want to add a reference of a user to the array of users which is a field of admin. For it I have the following code:

```py
    user_id = get_user_id(user_last_name, user_first_name)
    admin_id = get_admin_id(admin_last_name, admin_first_name)

    user_ref = db.collection(u'user').document(user_id)
    admin_ref = db.collection(u'admin').document(admin_id)

    admin_ref.update(
        {u'users': firestore.ArrayUnion([user_ref])})
```

But the code does not insert the reference to array of users. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/primrose/work/BE/db_api.py", line 109, in <module>
    test_run()
  File "/home/primrose/work/BE/db_api.py", line 106, in test_run
    add_user("...", "...", "...", "...")
  File "/home/primrose/work/BE/db_api.py", line 98, in add_user
    admin_ref.update(
  File "/home/primrose/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py", line 324, in update
    batch, kwargs = self._prep_update(field_updates, option, retry, timeout)
  File "/home/primrose/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_document.py", line 239, in _prep_update
    batch.update(self, field_updates, option=option)
  File "/home/primrose/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_batch.py", line 141, in update
    write_pbs = _helpers.pbs_for_update(
  File "/home/primrose/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 941, in pbs_for_update
    update_pb.update_transforms.extend(field_transform_pbs)
TypeError: Expected a message object, but got field_path: "users"
append_missing_elements {
  values {
    reference_value: ".../databases/(default)/documents/user/hlCcG1oFW4Z75JKqp1ZcfM8xWlh1"
  }
}
.
```

I had to omit the names and the beginning of the reference_value therefore they are "...". I do not understand the error, what could have caused the error? Shouldn't providing a field path be right?

When I try to get the information of the admin I get the following:

```py
    print(admin_ref.get().id, " => ", admin_ref.get().to_dict())
    {'users': [], 'email': '...', 'first_name': '...', 'last_name': '...'}
```

The used firebase_admin and protovuf version are:

```
Name: firebase-admin
Version: 5.2.0

Name: protobuf
Version: 4.21.2
```

The user_ref (former physio_ref before the edit, that name was not supposed to be in the question). the data I want to add to the array called "users" is a reference to another user.

Comment: What's the data of the variable `physio_ref`? Could you please include it in your question. And also, could you please include the version of your `firebase-admin` and `protobuf`.

Comment: physio_ref/user_ref is a reference to a user document stores in the firebase

Comment: Could you please try to downgrade your `protobuf` version to `3.20.1` using this command: `sudo pip3 install protobuf==3.20.1`. There are known issues with google cloud using the latest version of protobuf.

Comment: Have you already tried my suggestion?

Comment: HI, downgrading with to protobuf==3.20.1 solved my issue. (But I had installed without sudo, so I downgraded without sudo as well)

Comment: (I just saw the messages, also would you want to post it as an answer so that I can accept? It gave me a good headache when I first had the bug and could not find the solution)

Comment: Glad it worked! Already posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are known issues with Google Cloud Firestore using the latest version of `protobuf`. As confirmed by @Cherry Toska, downgrading `protobuf` to `3.20.1` solves the issue.

```
pip3 install protobuf==3.20.1
```